# setting uitabBarController shows internal error ios -objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

hi everyone i am working on an application with a tabBarController as initial viewController and my application worked just fine! until i updated to xcode 8.3 after the update this error happened:

> Main.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com .... .

after that i cleaned the project by trying Cmd + Shift + k and Cmd + shift + option + k multiple Times but nothing changed and the error message exist! does anybody know any solution ?

Comment: Do you know which portion this error causing?

Comment: in which xcode are you getting this error ? xcode 8.3 ? have you tried to run in older version ? have you tried quit and restart xcode ?

Comment: yes i quite and restarted xcode several times  even restarted  my computer  .but nothing changes if i change initial viewController to another viewcontroller it will build successfully but error comes on tabbarcontroller when it is initial viewcontroller

Comment: @arunjos007 in older version it was working and there was no error